# What do I have to put as return?

Tags: java, methods, counter

I just started learning Java. the task is to create a method that counts up from a value given by the user. An increase rate and an ending value are also given by the user. As I don't really know how to formulate it, here is an example:

Example:

**input:** Starting value (  `1` ), Increase (`2` ), Ending Value ( `10` )

**output :**

```
1,3,5,7,9
```

What to I have to put as return so that the class displays all numbers it counted (like in the example above)?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ForSchleifeÜbungen2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Bitte Startwert eingeben:");
        long Startwert = sc.nextLong();

        System.out.println("Bitte Schrittweite eingeben:");
        long Schrittweite = sc.nextLong();

        System.out.println("Bitte Endwert eingeben:");
        long Endwert = sc.nextLong();   

        System.out.println("Ihr Startwert: " + Startwert);
        System.out.println("Ihr Schrittweite: " + Schrittweite);
        System.out.println("Ihr Endwert: " + Endwert);

        System.out.println(Schrittzähler(Startwert, Schrittweite, Endwert));


        }



    public static long Schrittzähler (long Startwert, long Schrittweite, long Endwert) {

        long Zähler;

        for(long i = Startwert; i <= Endwert; i = i + Schrittweite) {
                    System.out.println(i);
        }

        long Zähler;

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the method should do in English as what as what it should return?  It doesn't appear the method needs to return anything so I would value the return type `void` and not try to print it as it already prints.

Comment: Instead of printing the numbers just add them to a string then return the string. Also, `long Zähler;` is not doing anything and you put it 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already did it, make slight modification here. you don't need to return as your requirement is just to print the numbers, so replace this

```
System.out.println(Schrittzähler(Startwert, Schrittweite, Endwert));
```

with

```
Schrittzähler(Startwert, Schrittweite, Endwert)
```

and change the signature of method as follows and remove `long Zähler;` it is unnecessary

```
   public static void Schrittzähler (long Startwert, long Schrittweite, long Endwert) {

        for(long i = Startwert; i <= Endwert; i = i + Schrittweite) {
                    System.out.println(i + ",");
        }

    }
```

**input :**

```
1, 2, 10
```

**output:**

```
1,3,5,7,9,
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called sum and give it an initial value of 0

```
long sum = 0; // I guess this is Zähler
```

At each iteration add the current `i` value to the sum like:

```
sum = sum + i; // alternatively sum += i;
```

Return sum at the end of the `Schrittzähler` method.

hint: By convention all Java variables are written in a camelCase starting with a small letter(not capital). The same is applicable for class members like methods and fields. [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: What's _arbitrary_ about the initial value?

Comment: @khelwood my english isn't any better than the OP's :)

Comment: OK. Well the initial value for the sum variable has to be zero in order for you to get the correct answer. So it's not arbitrary.

Comment: I've edited it to neutral since what I mean is that the initial value should not have any side effect. In a case of summing it's 0 , but in multiplication for example the neutral one is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder object to build the string of numbers to display. I took the liberty to change method, variable and parameter names to start with lowercase.

```
public static String schrittzähler(long startwert, long schrittweite, long endwert) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(startwert));
    for(long i = startwert + schrittweite; i <= endwert; i = i + schrittweite) {
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(i);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more eloquently, however, I believe something like this is what you are looking for. Let me know if you need any more assistance! The below code should be all things you understand as a new Java programmer. This is why I choose this solution.

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(returnNums(1,2,10));

  }
  public static String returnNums(int startNum, int increaseByNum, int endNum){
   
     String loopedNums = Integer.toString(startNum);

     while((startNum+increaseByNum) < endNum) {

           startNum = startNum + increaseByNum;
    loopedNums += Integer.toString(startNum)+"";
     
      }
      return loopedNums;
   }
}
```